# replace number list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list written in HTML:

```
<p>
1 - hello
2 - yo
3 - sup
</p>
```

I want to replace the **number [1-20]** followed by the **space[ ]** followed by the **hyphen[-]** with `&quot;<p class='answer'>&quot;`using Jquery.

---

I believe it is something like this? (obviously inside the `.find` is just explaining what I am looking for):

```
$( "p" ).find( "#[1-20] -" ).replaceWith( "&quot;<p class='answer'>&quot;" );
```

Comment: maybe you could start using a real unsorted html list instead of a paragraph tag? <ul><li></li>...</ul>

Comment: _Unclosed_ `p` element inside another `p` element? That's an invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clean<sup>(*)</sup> solution.

```
$("p:not(:has(*))").each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text(),
        linePattern = /^\s*(\d+) - (.*)/gm,
        line, paragraphs = [];

    if (linePattern.test(txt)) {
        linePattern.lastIndex = 0;
        while (line = linePattern.exec(txt)) {
            paragraphs.push( $("<p>", {text: '"' + line[2] + '"'}) );
        }
        $(this).replaceWith(paragraphs);
    }
});
```

<sup>(*)</sup> "Clean" as in: DOM-aware and XSS-safe, straight-forward and maintainable.

It converts

```
<p>
1 - hello
2 - yo
3 - sup
</p>
```

to

```
<p>"hello"</p><p>"yo"</p><p>"sup"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var htmlstr = $('p').html(); 
  var splitstr = htmlstr.split('-') ;
  var toreplace = splitstr[0];
  var replacewith = "&quot;<p class='answer'>&quot;";
  splitstr.replace(toreplace,replacewith )
```

Comment: `replace` don't change source string unlike `replaceWitn`

Comment: what output do you want from the html you mentioned in your question